# Inequality using double integals

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on some homework, and I came across a property of integrals I would like to use, but I have no idea if it is valid or not. Can we say:
$$
\left\vert{\int_U \int_B f  - \int_U \int_A f}\right\vert \leq \left\vert{\int_U \left(\int_B f - \int_A f\right)}\right\vert
$$
And if not, why not? This seems like a reasonable inequality to me, but I'm not sure how I would prove it.

Comment: The statement has 3 vertical lines .  Absolute value lines come in pairs.

Comment: Sorry there should be an absolute value after \int_U \int_A f

Comment: Aren't the two expressions inside the absolute values exactly the same mathematically? (if not, I suggest using the full notation rather than the shorthand notation to indicate the differences)

Comment: You should define all these objects. When properly defined, it will maybe appear as a trivial thing as @GregMartin is suggesting.